# SML type -> type -> type

Tags: sml

I'm struggling to understand this. Problem:

I have

```
datatype 'a tree= Leaf of 'a | Node of 'a tree * 'a * 'a tree
```

I have to find value in it using binary search. Here's my code.

```
fun binSearch ((Leaf n), x) = if n=x then true else false
  | binSearch ((Node (left, n, right)), x) =
        if n=x then true else
        if n>x then binSearch (left, x) else
        binSearch (right, x)
```

But I'm supposed to write function with this signature:

```
val binSearch : int tree -> int -> bool
```

I get the `int tree * int -> bool` part, but how do I do `'a -> 'b -> 'c`

Comment: Drive-by comment: `if C then true else false` is a complicated way of writing `C`. ;) Likewise, `if C then true else E` is just `C orelse E`.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg So if I get this right `1=1 orelse false` returns true and `1=2 orelse false` returns false. What if I write code instead of `false`?

Comment: `C orelse false` returns the same as `C`, so you wouldn't write that. `C1 orelse C2` is short for `if C1 then true else C2`. Similarly, there is `C1 andalso C2` as short for `if C1 then C2 else false`. Same as `||` and `&&` in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn a function of type `a * b -> c` into a function of type `a -> b -> c`, replace `fun f (x, y) = ...` with `fun f x y = ...`.

`fun f (x, y) = ...` defines a function that takes a tuple and automatically unpacks the tuple's values into the variables `x` and `y`. This is a syntactic short cut for `fun f tuple = case tuple of (x, y) => ...`. It leads to the type `a * b -> c` because `a * b` means "a tuple containing an `a` and a `b`". The function can then be called as `f (x, y)` or `f t` where `t` is a tuple.

`fun f x y = ...` on the other hand defines a so-called curried function, which is a function that takes the parameter `x` and then returns another function, which takes the parameter `y` and then returns the result. It is a syntactic shortcut for `fun f x = fn y => ...`. The function can then be called as `f x y` or `g y` where `g` has previously been set to `f x`.

Answer (score 0):

The signature `int tree * int -> bool` means that the function takes a pair `(int tree, int)` as input and outputs a `bool`.

The signature `int tree -> int -> bool` is equivalent to `int tree -> (int -> bool)`, and means that the function takes an `int tree` and outputs a function with signature `int -> bool`.

Signature `'a * 'b -> 'c` is obtained this way:

```
fun my_fun (a,b) = some_c
```

while signature `'a -> 'b -> 'c` is obtained this way:

```
fun my_fun a = fn b => some_c
```

That is, you have to create and return a lambda expression (an anonymous function created on the fly).

Also, remember that the first kind of function is called this way: `my_fun(my_tree,my_int)`, while the second kind this other way: `my_fun my_tree my_int`.